# How many numbers of length n can be made from {0,1,2} with at least one of each

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

My attempt:

Total number of n-length words made of 3 elements - $3^n$

Need to subtract sets made of 2 elements only - $3*2^n$

And add what we subtracted too many times - $3*1^n$

To sum up: $3^n-3*2^n+3$

Comment: For strings, perfect. For "decimal" three-digit numbers in which lead digit $0$ is forbidden, minor adjustment is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

community wiki post so that the question can be closed

Your solution is correct.